# Failure of $injector.invoke within a $routeProvider route's templateUrl function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

EDIT: I'm no longer actually trying to do what is outlined below, but I'd still love to know why it's not possible to use the $injector in this way.

---

I'm expecting there might be a valid reason I'm experiencing a failure in using $injector.invoke when calling it from a function defined for a route's templateUrl, but it would be good to get confirmation of that. If this should work, that'd be good to know also. :)

The failure is demonstrated in [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HwXpe2US5WUhJo2xv7XW). The sample has two uses of $injector.invoke. There are two clickable divs in the sample to trigger each use:
one triggers a call from a controller that works just fine
the other is a call from the route's templateUrl function which fails.

The JavaScript there is as follows:

```
function MyCtrl($location, $injector) {
  this.tryInjectorInvoke = function() {
    // This works
    $injector.invoke(function($rootScope) {
      alert('Have $rootScope? ' + !!$rootScope);
    });
  };
  // This is used to trigger a route change to the failing case.
  this.navTo = function(dest) {
    $location.path(dest);
  };
}

function configRoutes($routeProvider, $injector) {
  $routeProvider.when('/fails', {
    controller: 'MyCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    templateUrl: function() {
      try {
        // This fails horribly.
        $injector.invoke(function($rootScope) {
          return 'fails.html'
        });
      } catch (err) {
        alert('$injector.invoke failed!\n\n' + err);
      }
    }
  }).otherwise({
    controller: 'MyCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    templateUrl: 'works.html'
  });
}

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
myApp.config(configRoutes);
```

Comment: Thre are workarounds to achieve what you want, but why would you need the $injector in the `templateUrl` function ?

Comment: I've opted to re-work things so that I don't make use of the $injector in the templateUrl, but I was using it to alter the template used based on state exposed by a service. The use of $rootScope above was just for the minimal thing that exhibited the behavior.